# Java cup, How to Inject a function after each reduce in the generated parser file?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, cup

I'm using .cup file to generate parser based on specific derivation rules.

After every reduce, I want to call a function, Is it possible to define it anywhere in the .cup file, so that it will be injected into the generated code after each reduce?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently so, if you are using the version of Java CUP [maintained by Jochen Hoenecke on github.](https://github.com/ultimate-pa/javacup)
Quoting the manual (from that version, [end of section 2.2](https://rawgithub.com/ultimate-pa/javacup/master/manual.html)):

> `after reduce {: ... :};`
>
> Defines code that is executed whenever a production rule is reduced. The arrays symbols contains all terminal and non-terminal symbols of the current production rule. RESULT can be used to access and modify the value of the nonterminal created by the production rule. Example usage:
>
> ```
> after reduce {:
>    int lineNumber = symbols[0].left + 1;
>    if (RESULT instanceof AST_Node) {
>       ((AST_Node) RESULT).lineNumber = lineNumber
>    }
>  :}
> ```

According to the change log, the feature was added in 2019.